# Equivalent to cdable_vars in Powershell

Tags: powershell

On Linux with BASH or ZSH I can set an option for `cdable_vars` which allow me to define a shortcut for a folder.

For example:

```
export servo="/home/bleakcabal/Documents/servo/"
```

Lets me `cd` into this folder by doing:

```
cd servo
```

Is there something similar with Powershell? If so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Use the following code to create a system variable for the folder:

```
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP1","C:\temp1","Machine")
```

Where TEMP1 is the system variable name.
C:\temp1 is the path name.

You call it in Powershell with the `$env:<variable_name>` variable

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A normal variable will do the job in PowerShell just as well as an environment variable.

```
PS C:\> $temp1 = '/temp1'
PS C:\> cd $temp1
PS C:\temp1> _
```

If you *do* really want to do it without the `$` prefix, checkout [cd-extras](https://github.com/nickcox/cd-extras#cdable_vars).